# why the internet connection drops when Bluetooth earphones connected to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, internet, lts

I'm having oneplus Bluetooth earphones and when I connected it to my system the internet speed drops rapidly and even you tube won't work.

other apps like web-apps like MS teams, gmeet, Zoho call nothing works on Bluetooth

If I just replace Bluetooth earphone with wired earphone internet works lightning fast.

In previous Ubuntu 20 LTS version I didn't faced this issue. but, after upgrading to 22.04.2 LTS  I'm thinking why I did this mistake.

Edit: updates installed now even with new upadted kernal upon connecting bluetooth MS teams or Gmeet get disconnects and it will not work.

> lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1028:083c]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:1810]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e009 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:6a05 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I ran this command and got this

```
sudo ls /sys/kernel/debug/ieee80211/phy0/

aql_enable       hwflags        reset
aql_threshold        keys           rts_threshold
aql_txq_limit        long_retry_limit   short_retry_limit
aqm          misc           statistics
ath10k           netdev:p2p-dev-wlp3s0  total_ps_buffered
force_tx_status      netdev:wlp3s0      user_power
fragmentation_threshold  power          wep_iv
ht40allow_map        queues
hw_conf          rate_ctrl_alg
```

```
sudo ls /sys/kernel/debug/ieee80211/phy0/ath10k/


ani_enable  fw_stats         ps_state_enable    spectral_count
cal_data    htt_max_amsdu_ampdu  reg_addr       spectral_scan0
chip_id     htt_stats_mask       reg_value      spectral_scan_ctl
fw_checksums    mem_value        reset_htt_stats    sta_tid_stats_mask
fw_dbglog   nf_cal_period        simulate_fw_crash  tpc_stats
fw_reset_stats  pktlog_filter        spectral_bins  wmi_services
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb`

Comment: @Jeremy31 hey I updated he result please have a look at it

Comment: Try disabling wifi power management with `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` in terminal.  Can you switch to using wifi on 5GHz?

Comment: @Jeremy31 nothing happened. my wifi  router wont support 5G. it's normal one. also in ubuntu 18 or 20 lts version I never faced this issue. i.e internet calls not working upon Bluetooth connection.

Comment: Any result from terminal for `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/ieee80211/phy0/ath10k/btcoex`

Comment: @Jeremy31 `cat: /sys/kernel/debug/ieee80211/phy0/ath10k/btcoex: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `sudo ls sys/kernel/debug/ieee80211/phy0/`

Comment: @Jeremy31 updated question, getting this `ls: cannot access 'sys/kernel/debug/ieee80211/phy0/': No such file or directory`

Comment: @VikasAcharya you're missing a leading `/` on that path.  Jeremy didn't include it, and it's required.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thank you for guiding me, I have updated the result. kindly have a look. Also, I ran this cmd without connecting bluetooth device.

Comment: @Jeremy31 any update on this issue?

Comment: What results for `sudo ls /sys/kernel/debug/ieee80211/phy0/ath10k/`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have updated the results. please have a look.

Comment: It looks like there is no way to adjust the Bluetooth coexistence with ath10k

Comment: @Jeremy31 what do you mean by that? the problem with my system or OP?

Comment: The problem with your system

Comment: @Jeremy31 if i go back to ubuntu 20 or 18 will it solve the issue? can u elaborate what's the problem with system and how it's affecting bluetooth and internet in answer section.

Comment: I don't know if using an older Ubuntu version will help.  The problem is that wifi and bluetooth use the same frequencies and can interfere with each other